# Symfony not getting auth token

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, oauth, hwioauthbundle

I'm using the HWI OAuth bundle for Symfony. I log in with Amazon, but then my profiler toolbar says that there is no token, and that I am therefore not logged in.  But the tools to grab the token and user object work fine.  Why does the toolbar say there is no token, and will this screw up any other user-based features?

Comment: Can you please post more detail? What error message exactly are you getting?

Comment: There is no error message, just the profiler toolbar tells me that I am not authenticated and there was no token passed.

Comment: Reworded for clarity.